# Keytool command in Java?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, keytool

I have spent multiple hours trying to figure out the `keytool` CLI command for Java (in order to zipalign my Android app).

After a long search, I saw on another Stack Overflow Question that I should verify that I have the filepath, and after confirming the path to the binary was correct, I tried to check for the keytool; this is what happened:

```
 C:\Users\ealeo_000>dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_73/bin/keytool.exe"

 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 70C4-072A

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin

 File Not Found
```

According to what I've looked up, this should be the correct path; yet nothing is showing up. This leads me to believe that for some reason that `keytool` is not being installed along with the JDK...

Am I correct in assuming this? If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: You're showing a path to a JRE, the Java runtime environment, not a path to a JDK, the Java development kit. You need to download & install the JDK and then make sure it is used before the JRE.

Comment: Maybe check the 64 bit `Program Files` folder too.

Comment: Maarten, can you make it an answer so I can mark it resolved? I'm fairly sure that I cannot use the comment to do so...

Comment: And yes, I found it! Thank you! Yay!

Comment: Great, gotta go on one ear now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing a path to a JRE, the Java runtime environment, not a path to a JDK, the Java development kit. You need to download & install the JDK and then make sure it is used before the JRE.

Note that there are two `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` on 64 bit Windows machines where the Java installations may reside.